# how are we going to write def get_row_wise_counts_matrix(input_matrix): of the following scenario in python?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, numpy

Given an input matrix, output another matrix with the same shape such that every element of the output matrix gives the number of row-wise occurrences of its corresponding input matrix entry.
For example, given the following matrix:
                                4,5,3,5,3
                                1,3,2,4,2
                                4,4,5,5,4
The output matrix should be:
                                1,2,2,2,2
                                1,1,2,1,2
                                3,3,2,2,3

Comment: Have you tried any code yet? You shouldn't expect people to write all the code for you! https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi there! Great job posting your first question! Can you provide what you have so far? A bit more context and specifying your question with some code will grealty improve your change someone will come along able to help you